# Why is this table creation statement not resulting in the specified type?

Tags: mysql

I ran the following on two different hosts:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`mytable` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `updated` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created` DATETIME,
  `deleted` TINYINT DEFAULT 0,
  `notes` TEXT DEFAULT '',
  `description` VARCHAR(100),
  INDEX `deleted` (`deleted`)
) TYPE=innodb;
```

A table was created in both places. However at one of them the table type says "MyISAM" rather than "InnoDB". What gives?

**Edit: AH HA! "SHOW ENGINES" shows InnoDB as disabled. How do I enable it?**

Edit: here are the server variables that relate to InnoDB on the problem server:

```
innodb additional mem pool size 1,048,576
innodb autoextend increment 8
innodb buffer pool awe mem mb   0
innodb buffer pool size 8,388,608
innodb checksums    ON
innodb commit concurrency   0
innodb concurrency tickets  500
innodb data file path   
innodb data home dir    
innodb doublewrite  ON
innodb fast shutdown    1
innodb file io threads  4
innodb file per table   OFF
innodb flush log at trx commit  1
innodb flush method 
innodb force recovery   0
innodb lock wait timeout    50
innodb locks unsafe for binlog  OFF
innodb log arch dir 
innodb log archive  OFF
innodb log buffer size  1,048,576
innodb log file size    5,242,880
innodb log files in group   2
innodb log group home dir   
innodb max dirty pages pct  90
innodb max purge lag    0
innodb mirrored log groups  1
innodb open files   300
innodb rollback on timeout  OFF
innodb support xa   ON
innodb sync spin loops  20
innodb table locks  ON
innodb thread concurrency   8
innodb thread sleep delay   10,000
```

Comment: Are you sure the table was created? IF NOT EXISTS will be a no-op if the table was already there. In that case, the existing table definition will be preserved, even if it is different from the one you specified this time.

Comment: I am sure the table was created. The database had no tables before the operation.

Comment: MySQL client version: 5.0.51a

Comment: AH HA! "SHOW ENGINES" shows InnoDB as disabled. How do I enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh, there it was in my my.cnf file:

```
skip-innodb
```

Make that, there it was in my my.cnf file TWICE. So I commented them it out. Voila! InnoDB files are now able to be created.

Answer (score 2):

Say `ENGINE=InnoDB`, not <s>`TYPE`</s>.

Comment: I got the same result, the table that was created is of the type MyISAM.

Comment: Maybe the server doesn't have support for InnoDB on one of the hosts?

Comment: @Kenneth: Do you have InnoDB support built in? I just create a table with `engine=Garbage` and MySQL created it without complaint as a MyISAM table.

Comment: @mu: Moreover, requests for foreign key constraints get tacitly ignored, too.

Comment: @mu, perhaps it does not support InnoDB. How do I check if it does and how do I make it do so if it does not already?

Comment: The whole "quietly ignoring" thing is the leading cause of "mu wants to set MySQL on fire and dance on its ashes".

Comment: @mu: Hehe, a very polite database. It never complains. Have you tried the blackhole engine? ;-)